# Язык Си, преобразование целых чисел

Tags: c

могли бы вы объяснить, по какому принципу в языке C происходит целочисленное преобразование в следующем случае:

```
signed char sc = -1;
unsigned int ui = sc;
```

В ассемблерном листинге (компилятор x32) вторая строчка представлена как **movsbl** (поместить знаковое из байта в длинное).

Получается, что знаковое меньшей размерности сперва преобразуется в знаковое большей размерности, а только потом - в беззнаковое.

Почему так?

Понятно, что если преобразование пойдет по пути:

```
signed char -> unsigned char -> unsigned int
```

То итоговый результат получится совсем другой - он окажется в пределах вместимости беззнакового меньшей размерности, в нашем случае **[0;255]**.

Вопрос меня беспокоит потому, что при сравнении чисел, в нашем случае - целых, оба числа должны быть одинакового типа - наиболее широкого.

И, например, такой код:

```
signed char sc = ...;
unsigned int ui = ...;
if (sc < ui) {...}
```

Вызывает некоторые трудности в понимании происходящего.

При сравнениях знакового с беззнаковым одинаковой размерности - все понятно: знаковое преобразуется в беззнаковое (мнимое расширение), на практически всех современных машинах битовое представление числа не меняется, потому что целые представлены в дополнительном коде.

При сравнениях целых разной размерности, но одинакового знака, - тоже все понятно.

А вот сравнение целых, и размерность, и знаковость которых различаются, понимается мной с трудом.

Помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Наткнулся на [такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe), вроде оно. Если я правильно понял то там сказано если сравнение знакового отрицательного с без знаковым, то без знаковый приводится к `UINT_MAX`. Мог напутать...

Comment: Хотелось бы прочитать эти объяснения на русском языке, в таких тонких вещах мои знания английского, как и использование переводчика, недостаточны.

Comment: @Максим хорошо я попробую перевести и добавить в ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо!